# SVN access control is not working

Tags: svn

I have a project in svn repository, which contains more branches and tags, and several users are working in the same project but in different branches. I gave write permission to particular user to access particular branch only, but not to other branches, and similarly for another user to write to yet different branch.

Step 1 : I have create user using

```
htpasswd -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd username
```

Step 2 : svnserve.conf

```
[general]
password-db = passwd
realm = reponame
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
authz-db = authz
```

Step 3 : passwd

```
username : passwd
```

Added user & passwd which are used for creating htpasswd for this project in passwd file.

Step 4 : authz

```
#[the_name_of_repository:/path_in_that_repository]
[test:/]
user1 = r
user2 = r

[test:/branches/data1]
user1 : rw

[test:/branches/data2]
user2 : rw
```

So, now `user2` can only access (commit, update, checkout) `data2` branches and can read all other folders, and `user2` can access (commit, update, checkout) `data1` branch. Access control is not working properly as expected from `authz` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No reason to close the question. It's both on topic for SO and fairly clear.

Comment: If you meant to say "`user1` can access `data1`", then your rules are all correct. What you haven't explained is how you serve your repository (Apache, svnserve, svnserve+ssh) and how you're pointing to your configurations there.

Comment: Also, is your file really `svnserver.conf`? The default is `svnserve.conf` (note the lack of an **r**).

Comment: user1 can able to access data2 also but i gave only read permission for user1 to data2 branch. installed subversion in centos.

Comment: sorry svnserver.conf only wrongly typed. now changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may stem from something @alroc said in the comments.  You're configuring permissions using svnserve.conf, but you created the user for Apache.

Apache's mod_dav_svn doesn't read svnserve.conf.  Instead, you need to [install mod_authz_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) and [set up an AuthzSVNAccessFile](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) for it.  This file appears to have the same syntax as svnserve.conf.

Comment: Actually, re-reading this, you may have already set up mod_authz_svn... I'll leave this answer here anyway in case it's useful for someone else who comes along.

Comment: configured as you mentioned as AuthzSVNAccessFile in centos but getting forbidden error while accessing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must to know, which type of repository (http-based, served by Apache, or svn-based, served by svnserve) you have and use only one from two independent and unrelated type of authentication: `htpasswd` for apache, `passwd` for svnserve
2. Auth-database must have at least user1+user2 records
3. `authz` file must use correct syntax in all records: you have mistakes in both branches, corrrect format is

`object = rights`